# Loading external html file in to popover

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

This is my html mockup,

```
<li tabindex='+len+' rel="popover" data-poload="templates/workInProcessDetail.html"class="pop" data-placement="left"></li>
```

Jquery:

```
$(".pop").popover({ title: 'Look! A bird!' });
```

I need to popover an external html file in to that popover, please help me out

Comment: I don't see any html there

Comment: my bad here is the html:

Comment: <li tabindex='+len+' rel="popover" class="pop" data-placement="left"></li>

Comment: what version are you using?

Comment: iam using bootstrap 3

Comment: could you edit the question in order to have everything in one place?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
$(".pop").popover({
    title: 'Look! A bird!',
    html: true,
    content: function () {
        $.get('path to html').success(function (data) {
            return data;
        });
    }
});
```

Demo:http://jsfiddle.net/AmitJoki/szkrx/65/

Comment: this your answer would have worked for all situation supposing the ajax call is written like this     $.get('path to html', function(data) { //handle returned data } NOTE that you can not return response had denoted in your code as $.get runs async. what i did in my case was to use the the popver-body class with the $.get block like this $(".popover-body").html(data); which work excellently. I hope this help somebody.

Answer (score 0):

This is the working code for this situation taking clue from Amit Joki's Answer above.

```
$(".pop").popover({
    title: 'Your title',
    html: true,
    content: function () {
        $.get('path to html file', function (data) {
          $(".popover-body").html(data);
          $(".popover-body").css("padding", "20px");
        });
    }
});
```